# When performing an INNER JOIN on two tables, which table should I reference for duplicate column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I am joining, the EventRequest table and the Customer table. The Customer.CustNo is a primary key and the EventRequest.CustNo is a foreign key:

```
SELECT EventNo, DateHeld, Customer.CustNo, CustName
FROM EventRequest
INNER JOIN Customer ON EventRequest.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
```

My question is, is there any difference between using Customer.CustNo instead of EventRequst.CustNo in the SELECT statement when doing an INNER JOIN? Is one preferred over the other and why?

Comment: No they both will return the same result.  I prefer using the primary key when applicable.

Comment: Customer.CustNo instead of EventRequst.CustNo? what does that mean

Comment: Since you are retrieving columns from both tables there is no difference. There could be a difference if `CustNo` was the only column retrieved from `Customer`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, but I prefer use the field of the main table.
Or the field from the table that you are retrieving more fields.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter which table's column you reference to make an inner join as long as 2 tables have the column name same. I would prefer using the primary key column.

Comment: you said => as long as 2 tables have the column name same? that is not correct